# Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(); produce a "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

```
function setOutcome(result) {
    if (result.token) {
        Stripe.apiKey = "my_key";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("amount", 1000);
        params.put("currency", "chf");
        Charge charge = Charge.create(params);
    } else if (result.error) {
        ...
    }
}
```

will produce an "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" error. Any suggestions?

edit: You are right, I add this in my javascript section on my website. Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: Your code looks like Java rather than Javascript

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Did you import `HashMap`?

Comment: i just imported the Stripe library: https://js.stripe.com/v3/

Comment: "solved" i realized the charge with curl in the next step.